# jquery widget factory - can I declare global variables at _create or outside the widget?

Tags: jquery, variables, widget, global-variables

I'm trying to make my first Jquery widget using the [widget factory](http://ajpiano.com/widgetfactory/#slide1).

I have 10 functions inside my widget and wanted to declare variables used throughout on _create like so:

```
(function($,window){
$.widget("mobile.somesome",$.mobile.widget, {

    _create: function() {           

        var self = this,
            that = something else, ...
```

I want to access these variables from within the other functions, but this does not work or more likely... I'm doing something wrong...

Question:
Is it possible to declare variables on a "widget-global" level and if so how can I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could declare them as properties and them set/access them throughout the widget:

```
(function($) {
    $.widget("mywidget", {
        vars: {
            a: 1,
            b: 2 // etc.
        },

        _create: function() {  
            var x = this.vars.a;   
            this.vars.b = x + 1;   
        .
        .
        .
```

Comment: just wanted to say you need ":". Works! Thank you very much!

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that those properties will not be "per instance" specific. Meaning, if you instantiated your widget on two or more DOM elements on the same page, you'll be sharing those property values instead of having its own instance of them.

Comment: How to set a global array? I tried 'list : []' but not working